# Accessing nested Javascript object with variables

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the sum of each channel to get the total energy for energy_ac. This is the mapping.

```
var mappings = [
{
  floor: 13,
  name: 1301,
  room_type: 'room',
  energy_ac: [
    {deviceId: 15062, channels: ['ct1']},
    {deviceId: 15063, channels: ['ct1', 'ct2', 'ct3']}
  ],
  energy_light: [
    {deviceId: 15062, channels: ['ct4']}
  ],
  energy_socket1: [
    {deviceId: 15062, channels: ['ct5']}
  ],
  energy_socket2: [
    {deviceId: 15062, channels: ['ct5']}
  ]
}  ];
```

This is the data:

```
data = { '15062':
   { _id: 550fea1b46758f1505dd70c7,
 deviceId: '15062',
 link: 'http://egauge15062.egaug.es/cgi-bin/egauge-show?S&s=0&n=6&C&Z=LST-8',
 timestamp: 1427106327,
 ct1: 34,
 ct2: 0,
 ct3: 7,
 ct4: 572,
 ct5: 527 },
  '15063':
   { _id: 550fea1b46758f1505dd70c8,
 deviceId: '15063',
 link: 'http://egauge15062.egaug.es/cgi-bin/egauge-show?S&s=0&n=6&C&Z=LST-8',
 timestamp: 1427106327,
 ct1: 34,
 ct2: 0,
 ct3: 7,
 ct4: 572,
 ct5: 527 },
  '15064':
{ _id: 550fea1b46758f1505dd70c9,
 deviceId: '15064',
 link: 'http://egauge15062.egaug.es/cgi-bin/egauge-show?S&s=0&n=6&C&Z=LST-8',
 timestamp: 1427106327,
 ct1: 34,
 ct2: 0,
 ct3: 7,
 ct4: 572,
 ct5: 527 },
  '15065':
   { _id: 550fea1b46758f1505dd70ca,
 deviceId: '15065',
 link: 'http://egauge15062.egaug.es/cgi-bin/egauge-show?S&s=0&n=6&C&Z=LST-8',
 timestamp: 1427106327,
 ct1: 34,
 ct2: 0,
 ct3: 7,
 ct4: 572,
 ct5: 527 } }
```

This is my code:

```
mappings.forEach(function(room) {
  var hash = {};
  hash.floor = room.floor;
  hash.name = room.name;
  hash.room_type = room.room_type;
  hash.energy_ac = 0;
  room.energy_ac.forEach(function(device) {
    device.channels.forEach(function(channel){
      hash.energy_ac += room[device][channel];
    });
  });
```

room[device][channel] is not working for me. I also tried room[device].channel . I am not sure how to get the value of channel. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: I posted my actual code, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device is nested inside of energy_ac, so you can't access it directly from room. You need to do something like `room.energy_ac[device].channels[channel]`. This still isn't going to work though, because channel isn't the index of the array, it's the current item, which is the channel value. What you really need to do is just run `hash.energy_ac += channel`, since channel is the number you want to add anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the chief problem here is that you're attempting to get the energy from the `device` object, when it's actually stored in the `data` object. The *keys* you need to index into the `data` object are stored in `device`.

Assuming you want the total energy_ac per room, what you need to do is:

```
for each room:
    set hash.energy_ac = 0
    for each device in room's energy_ac:
        for each channel in this device:
          add the energy of this device and channel to hash.energy_ac
```

So for the one room in `mappings` (1301), the `energy_ac` should be 75. Its `energy_ac` is comprised of device 15062: channel ct1 (34), plus device 15063: channels ct1 (34) + ct2 (0) + ct3 (7). 34 + 34 + 7 = 75.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ca9yjts/) with (what I think is) the implementation you intended.

Also, I was getting console errors due to the `_id` values not being strings.